# Styling Posts Archive dynamically using Flexbox

Tags: php, html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm trying to find the best way to style my columns. If there are 4 posts then it works as hoped. But if a row has less than 4, there is additional space between each post. I know this is possible with floats but I'm hoping there is a more modern solution to this, **ideally using flexbox**. This is how it is currently set up. The second row is spaced differently than the first row.[image: This is how it is currently set up. The second row is spaced differently than the first row]

This is the desired layout with all columns in line with each other

[image: Picture 2 Is the desired layout.]

PHP

```
<div class="news-results">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Each News Preview Card -->
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="<?php echo $preview_image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3><?php echo $title; ?></h3>
        <p><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p>
        <p><?php echo $date; ?></p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS

```
.news-results {
  .container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
    .news-card {
      width: calc(25% - 20px);
      .image-background,
      .color-background {
        height: 215px;
        width: auto;
        margin-bottom: 15px;
      }
      img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
      }
      .news-contents {
        h3, p {
          color: $black;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**
Also, I need the posts to fill  .container div so margin-right on all of them would not work. See img:[image]
Thanks for your help!! :D

Answer (score 1):

You definitely don't want to use `justify-content: space-between;`, because that is what is causing the content to be equally space when there aren't 4 flex items. You can try something like this where the `flex` parent has `flex-wrap: wrap;` and each `flex-item` has a calculated `width` with some sort of spacing.

This way, each column will take up roughly `25%` all the time, unless instructed otherwise by a `media` style for example.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

a.news-card {
  width: calc(100%/4);
  text-align: center;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  a.news-card {
    width: calc(100%/2);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
  a.news-card {
    width: calc(100%/1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="news-results">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Each News Preview Card -->
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>" class="news-card">
      <div class="image-background">
        <img src="https://dummyimage.com/200/000/fff" alt="<?php echo $preview_image['alt']; ?>">
      </div>
      <div class="news-contents">
        <h3>Title</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Pariatur eum</p>
        <p>Date</p>
      </div>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Kameron. This works except the 4th post in the row has the margin added to it which prohibits it from taking up the whole container for the posts. I want to keep a consistent container line throughout the page. Do you have a way to do this if the row has 4 posts then it will take up the whole container's width?

Comment: @KyleKlaiber As you can see in the markup there is an inline `style="margin: 0;"` added to the fourth flex-item.

Comment: Yeah but I'm looking to do this dynamically. So any post that is divisible by 4 (on desktop, 3 on tablet, 2 on mobile) would not have margin-right applied. So I'd rather not do inline styles because that opens up some other challenges.

Comment: @KyleKlaiber Lol, then lose the `margin` completely then. Was trying to help you out with spacing on mobile, not make you more confused. See edits for an example of what you could do for `media queries.

Comment: I appreciate the help but removing the margin doesn't get me where I'd like to be. But it did get me thinking...when i loop through the posts I can add a class to posts divisible by 4, then a different class to those divisible by 3, and a different class for those divisible by 2. By doing that I can remove the margin-right on 3 on tablet and 2 on mobile through the class via media queries.

Comment: @KyleKlaiber Okay. You're initial desired solution was "the desired layout with all columns in line with each other" as shown in the image. Which is what my solution handles. If there is something else you want, please update the question.. I don't understand what you mean by the most recent comment...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244814/discussion-between-kameron-and-kyle-klaiber).